# Closed Poincaré dual, why $\int_M \omega \wedge \eta_S$ and not $\int_M \eta_S \wedge \omega $?

Tags: integration, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This question might be the same as this: [Definition of closed Poincaré dual](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166664/definition-of-closed-poincar%C3%A9-dual) (I didn't read too carefully) but there is no answer.

My book is Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott of which An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu is a prequel.

The characterization of the closed Poincaré dual is given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSgf9.png) (the "(5.13)") in Section 5.5. This has $\int_M \omega \wedge \eta_S$, where $\eta_S$ is on the **right rather than left**.

**Question**: Why is it $\int_M \omega \wedge \eta_S$, where $\eta_S$ is on the **right rather than left**?

- **Update**: The book made a mistake. See my question on [overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333131/closed-poincar%C3%A9-dual-why-int-m-omega-wedge-eta-s-and-not-int-m-eta-s).