# Definition of Poincare Duality: Integral descend to cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, differential-topology, de-rham-cohomology, poincare-duality

In Bott & Tu's "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" on page 50 & 51, the authors define the Poincare dual of a submanifold as follows:

Let $M$ be an oriented smooth manifold of dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $i: S \rightarrow M$ a smooth submanifold of dimension $0 \leq k \leq n$ which is closed. Here the authors specify that "closed" means closed as a topological subspace of $M$. Once can now show that pulling back a compactly supported form on $M$ along the inclusion gives a compactly supported form on $S$. Let $\omega \in \Omega^k_c (M)$ be closed, then since $S$ is orientable the assignment $\omega \mapsto \int_S i^*(\omega)$ gives a well defined linear functional $\int_S i^*(-): \Omega^k_c (M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now the authors state that "by Stokes's Theorem, integration over $S$ induces a linear functional on $H^k_c(M)$". But I fail to see why this is.

We need to check that the functional vanishes on exact $k$-forms. So let $d \omega \in \Omega^k_c (M)$ be exact. Then

$$ \int_S i^*(d \omega) = \int_S d (i^*(\omega)) = \int_{\partial S} i^*(\omega)$$

In the first equality we apply that pullbacks commute with the differential while in the second we apply Stokes's theorem. However, I fail to see why the latter integral is $0$. If the boundary of $S$ was empty, this would be the case, but we only assume $S$ to be closed as a topological subspace, not as a manifold (i.e. compact and empty boundary).

For example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166664/definition-of-closed-poincar%C3%A9-dual) question assumes $S$ to have empty boundary. Could it be that Bott & Tu assume $S$ to be closed (in the stronger sense of compact and no boundary). That would also imply that $S$ is closed as a topological subspace.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It seems it depends on what is a submanifold. In Tu's Introduction to manifolds, a submanifold do not have boundary.

Comment: I see. That's probably it. Thank you